# Django: How to make a form for `key: value` pairs?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model `Label` for keeping strings that appear in my site:

```python
class Label(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True, default='')
```

And I want to make a form to customize these strings. Looks like this:

```
Site Configuration
this_is_key: this_is_value_____________
site_title: ________________
site_subtitle: _________________
site_copyright_info: _________________
admin_email: _________________
admin_phone: _________________
[Save]
```

And when the value of any key is not existed, `Label.create()` with our pre-defined default value for that.

Now, how to use `forms.Form` or `forms.ModelForm` (or something else whatever... I don't sure if something like `formset` is used to do this task) to finish this job? I've been seeking for solution for several days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My little solution. https://kuanyui.github.io/2015/08/10/django-key-value-pairs-model-and-form/

### `settings.py`

Define your labels in `settings.py`:

```python
LABELS = [
    # ('key', 'label in form', 'default value'),
    ('site_title'     , 'Site Title',     'Hello World!'),
    ('copyright_info' , 'Copyright Info', 'John Smith (c) 2015'),
    ('admin_email'    , 'Your E-mail',    '02 1234 5678'),
]
```

### models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Label(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True, default='')

    @classmethod
    def get_label(cls, key):

        """Get the value of a label via key.
        If not found, create one with the default value in
        settings.LABELS."""

        try:
            return cls.objects.get(key=key).value
        except:
            default_value = [x for x in settings.LABELS if x[0] == key][0]
            cls.objects.create(key=key, value=default_value)
            return default_value
```

### forms.py

We define `save()` method to save `request.POST` into our model.

```
from django import forms
from pages.models import Label
from django.conf import settings

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, Div, Button, Fieldset, HTML

class LabelForm(forms.Form):    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key, label, default_value in settings.LABELS: # settings.LABELS
            self.fields[key] = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
            self.fields[key].label = label

            # get_or_create => (<Label: Label object>, False)
            labelObj, _ = Label.objects.get_or_create(
                key=key,
                defaults={'value': default_value})
            self.fields[key].initial = labelObj.value

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))

    def save(self, POST):
        for key, _, _ in settings.LABELS:
            Label.objects.filter(key=key).update(value=POST[key])
```

### views.py

```
from pages.models import Label
from pages.forms import LabelForm

class LabelSettings(FormView):

    template_name = "label_settings.html"
    form_class = LabelForm
    success_url = '.'   # whatever.

    def form_valid(self, form):
        super().form_valid(form)
        form.save(self.request.POST)   # pass POST dict to LabelForm.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

### `label_settings.html`

This page is used to edit/save our labels.

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% crispy form %}
</form>
```

## Use In Template

### templatetags/common_tags.py

```
from django import template
from pages.models import Label
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def label(key):
    return Label.get_label(key)
```

### In template

```
{% load common_tags %}
<h1>{% label 'site_title' %}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear you're going to be able to use forms.Forms for this without writing an entire new library. You're asking to create a forms model at run time essentially which in my opinion is going to be very difficult to do.

My suggestion would be to just write your own custom forms classes if this is the approach you want to take. However, be aware that any validations or other features you want included will have to be stored in the database with each Label. So if you want a given label to have 150 character max you'll have to store that along with the key and value so that you can perform your own validations at run time

Comment: What is "my own custom forms classes" meaning? May I have further details?

Comment: Any of the functionality that forms.Forms currently provides you'll have to write on your own to work with your implementation. So for example: you want to be able to apply validation rules. You store the validation rule with the label and then you'll have to write custom classes so that you can check those validation rules

Comment: But my question is still stuck in how to "write my own custom form class"...orz

Comment: You're moving outside the scope of the original question. I'm not going to architect an entire solution for you. If you're asking how to put code in your own Python file and then reference it then that's also a separate question.

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot understand your answer&explanation, nor how to open&ask another question (Now my question is "I totally don't know how to ask this question")...
I doesn't intend to ask someone to make a full solution to do this. Instead, what I need are some hints.